# SOAP request with attribute

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I can not seem to find out how to set an attribute to a SOAP request without using the **XSD_ANYXML** encoding.

The request parameter should look as follows

```
<request
    xmlns:ns="/some/ns">
    ...
        <ns:parameter attr="some attribute">
            value
        </ns:parameter>
    ...
</request>
```

Of course the following code works, but it's rather ugly (ugly, because it uses string concatenation where it should **use the SOAP_Client API** and because it does not use the general namespace)

```
$param = new SoapVar(
    '<ns_xxx:parameter xmlns:ns_xxx="/some/ns" attr="some attribute">
        value
     </ns_xxx:parameter>',
    XSD_ANYXML
);
```

Is there a better way to create a SOAP request parameter with a namespace and an attribute?

I am looking for s.th. like the following (this is just some pseudo code using the [SoapVar](http://php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php) API):

```
$param = new SoapVar(
    array(
        '_' => 'value',
        'attr' => 'some attribute'
    ), 
    SOME_ENCODING,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    '/some/ns'
);
```

Comment: I'm not as well-versed at SOAP as I want to be, but does it support requests with attributes? (I know the WSDL has attributes, but how does it handle attributes in the XML sent to it?) Are you creating the service or is already set up? If it's your service, I would drop the attribute part and move it to it's own element within the parameter. Maybe as a no-value element, like `<someattribute />`

Comment: @Anthony: i unfortunately do not control the SOAP server and have no influence over the service definition ;( else, of course, i could just make the attribute an element.

Comment: Hello! I have a same issue. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

For this, you need to derived the class from SoapClient and Override the method __doRequest():

```
class ABRSoapClient extends SoapClient {

    // return xml request
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $xml= $dom->loadXML($request);
        // Goto request Node and Set the attribute
        $attr_ns = $dom->createAttributeNS('xmlns:ns', '' ); // instead of xmlns:ns use Namespace URL
        $attr_ns->value = '/some/ns';
        // add atribute in businessReport node 
        $dom->getElementsByTagName($report_type)->item(0)->appendChild( $attr_ns );   
        $request = $dom->saveXML();
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
    }
}

$client = new ABRSoapClient(.....);
$save_result = $client->request($param);

// You can check the form request using function
$client->__getLastRequest();
```

I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I didn't know how to customize the __doRequest function, but I had this one line of code in it and it worked:  

//Substitute namespace to all known types
$request = str_replace('RequestBase', 'ns1:RequestBase', $request);
return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);

Answer (score 0):

SOAP does not support attributes, may be you should use REST instead!

**EDIT:**
Please check the body style w3c:"4.3 SOAP Body" and remember that
 you need to encode your message with "soap-envelope" namespace and describe
your XML types thats why, you can't use attributes to describe your message data.

But if you ask me, it can be made possible! You can use a custom SoapClient parser or something like that and convert your message as you like it.
A example of that may be RSS over SOAP http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soaprdf.
But, the problem would be that you would miss the descriptive information about your message data/types and other clients could not easy understand your messages!

My best practice for you would be to use elements instead of attributes,
i know you need to fix your XML schema but thats the way it goes or switch to a other technology.

Comment: i understand your liking of REST over SOAP. yet this answer really does not help at all. it does not help to tell people, not to use a technology, when they try to solve a problem in that particular technology. plus, what you write is simlpy wrong: SOAP does support attributes. c.f. http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383492

Comment: No i prefer SOAP over REST. I'm developing with SOAP and PHP webservices for a couple of years now. I've modified my answer a bit, i hope this helps.

Comment: RAB's response is technically correct. The problem is that some implementers will require data be passed in attributes anyway. PHP's SoapVar implementation on the other hand follows the letter of the law and doesn't help out with attributes like a normal XML library would.

Answer (score -3):

SOAP 1 does support attributes.  Here is an example of Perl code using both attributes and values (from a client):

```
$som = $client->call(
    'tran:getContent',
    SOAP::Header->name('cred:credentials')->attr({
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'customerID' => 'xxx'}
    ),
    SOAP::Data->name('contentID')->value('9999')
)
```

Comment: Too bad the question was about PHP and not Prel.