# PHP SOAP Client Values and Attributes Not Loading

Tags: php, xml, soap-client

I am trying to make a SOAP call using PHP5.  Here is the working schema:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cat="http://com.xxx.xxxx/management/catalog">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <cat:ManageCustomProducts siteId="0">
     <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
     <!--0 to 25 repetitions:-->
     <cat:task id="?">
        <cat:insertCustomProduct manufacturerId="?" manufacturerPartNo="?" categoryId="?" categoryType="default">
           <cat:skus>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
              <cat:sku type="?" number="?"/>
           </cat:skus>
           <cat:resources>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
              <cat:resource type="?" status="?" url="?"/>
           </cat:resources>
           <cat:locales>
              <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
              <cat:locale language="?" country="?">
                 <cat:descriptions>
                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                    <cat:description type="?">e gero</cat:description>
                 </cat:descriptions>
                 <cat:marketingDescription>cum sonoras</cat:marketingDescription>
              </cat:locale>
           </cat:locales>
        </cat:insertCustomProduct>
     </cat:task>
  </cat:ManageCustomProducts>
```

Here is my code to generate the SOAP XML...

```
$params=array(array(
            'siteId' => '0',
            'task' => array('id' => '1',
                'insertCustomProduct' => array('manufacturerId' => '10000', 'manufacturerPartNo' => 'abc123', 'categoryId' => '20000', 'categoryType' => 'default', 
                                                    'skus' => array('sku' => array('type' => 'MANUFACTURPARTNO', 'number' => 'abc123')),
                                                    'resources' => array('resource' => array('type' => '500', 'status' => 'Published', 'url' => 'http://content.xxx.com/img.jpg')),
                                                    'locales' => array('locale' => array('language' => 'en', 'country' => 'US', 
                                                                                    'descriptions' => array('description' => array('_' =>'egeros', 'type' => '1')),
                                                                                    'marketingDescription' => array('_' => 'cum sonoras')
                                                                                    )
                                                                       )
                                              )
                           )
                )
        ); 

$result = $client->__soapCall("ManageCustomProducts",$params);
```

Here is the result...

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://com.xxx.xxx/management/catalog">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:ManageCustomProducts siteId="0">
     <ns1:task id="1">
        <ns1:insertCustomProduct manufacturerId="10000" manufacturerPartNo="abc123" categoryId="20000" categoryType="default">
           <ns1:skus>
              <ns1:sku type="MANUFACTURPARTNO" number="abc123"/>
           </ns1:skus>
           <ns1:resources>
              <ns1:resource type="500" status="Published" url="http://content.xxx.com/img.jpg"/>
           </ns1:resources>
           <ns1:locales>
              <ns1:locale language="en" country="US">
                 <ns1:descriptions>
                    <ns1:description type="1"/>
                 </ns1:descriptions>
                 <ns1:marketingDescription/>
              </ns1:locale>
           </ns1:locales>
        </ns1:insertCustomProduct>
     </ns1:task>
  </ns1:ManageCustomProducts>
```

Even though I am using the suggested format of:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419407/3280665

array("foo" => array("_" => "cheese", "bar"=>"moo"));

This should produce following XML

```
<foo bar="moo">cheese</foo>`
```

It is not adding the element value for description or marketingDescription.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Update:  I can now add the nodes, but how do I add the Type attribute to the description node?

```
$desc=array();
$desc[]=new SoapVar("This is description 1",XSD_STRING,null,null,'ns1:description');
$desc[]=new SoapVar("This is description 2",XSD_STRING,null,null,'ns1:description');
$description = new SoapVar($desc, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null,null,'description');'
```

Comment: you can use SoapVar to create params and check if this solve your problem [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php)

Comment: I can now add the nodes, but how do I add the description attribute of type?

Comment: are you try the three first comments in soapvar documentation? I mean maybe changing "This is description 1" to array('description' => array('_' =>'egeros', 'type' => '1')) maybe works...

Comment: [Could you solve this earlier question of yours?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21609905/367456) If yes, please leave an answer.

Comment: Unfortunatly "This is description 1" to array('description' => array('_' =>'egeros', 'type' => '1')) does not work :(